# AS3 Moving on to next frame after embedded YouTube Video finishes

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube, flash-cs4

I've embedded a video from YouTube into an SWF and I'm trying to make it so that when the video ends, the next frame will play.

Here is the function I am using.

```
    function onPlayerStateChange(event:Event):void {
        // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the new player state
        trace("player state:", Object(event).data);

        var State = ("player state:", Object(event).data);

        if (State == 0)
        gotoAndPlay(3);

    }
```

I've been searching for an answer for quite a while now :(

Comment: How are you embedding the video from Youtube?

Comment: Since I couldn't find a solution, and my previous tutorial's website is gone, I have found another way of presenting the contents in the flash project I was making.